# Coefficient Variable Membership in R

Tags: r, names, lm, model.matrix

I have worked up a horribly lengthy solution to this before using regular expressions but I hope  there is a more native way to do it.

Given a model, perhaps like

```
data(tips, package="reshape2")
mod <- lm(tip ~ total_bill*sex + sex*day, tips)
mod$coefficients
```

I want to identify which coefficients go with which variable in the formula.  Like this:

```
|    Coefficient     |    Variable    |
|:-------------------|:---------------|
| total_bill         | total_bill     |
| sexMale            | sex            |
| daySat             | day            |
| daySun             | day            |
| dayThur            | day            |
| total_bill:sexMale | total_bill,sex |
| sexMale:daySat     | sex,day        |
| sexMale:daySun     | sex,day        |
| sexMale:dayThur    | sex,day        |
```

I have inspected `model.matrix` and `model.formula` but those led me to this line of code

```
.Internal(model.matrix(t, data))
```

I dove into the C code but I figured there had to be an easier way.  Is there?

In response to DWin's nice answer I have built a convoluted example where the the regex could fail.  This is one of those edge cases where regex scares me.

The `data.frame` is built with variable names and values that can easily be confused which happens a lot.

```
baseball <- data.frame(Bat=sample(1:100, 20, replace=T), Batter=sample(c("David", "Batley", "Bob", "Ace"), 20, replace=T), Hits=sample(1:20, 20, replace=T))
baseball
bMod <- lm(Hits ~ Bat*Batter, baseball)
bMod$coefficients

col.matx <- sapply(colnames(model.matrix(bMod)), function(cols) sapply(labels(bMod), function(trm) grep(patt=trm, x=cols, value=TRUE)))
```

This matches the continuous variable `Bat` to all the coefficients for the `factor` `Batter`.

Yes, this is a stupid example, but can easily happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution for lm models using information entirely included in the model.

```
require(plyr)       # for join function
require(reshape2)   # for melt function

matchCoefs <- function(model)
{
    # get the terms
    theTerms <- model$terms
    # get the assignment position
    thePos <- model$assign
    # get intercept indicator
    inter <- attr(theTerms, "intercept")
    # get coef names
    coefNames <- names(coef(model))
    # get pred names
    predNames <- attr(theTerms, "term.labels")
    # expand out pred names to match coefficient names
    predNames <- predNames[thePos]
    # if there's an intercept term add it to the pred names
    if(inter == 1)
    {
        predNames <- c("(Intercept)", predNames)
    }

    # build data.frame linking term to coefficient name
    matching <- data.frame(Term=predNames, Coefficient=coefNames)

    ## now match individual predictor to term
    # get matrix as data.frame
    factorMat <- as.data.frame(attr(theTerms, "factor"))
    # add column from rownames as identifier
    factorMat$.Pred <- rownames(factorMat)
    # melt it down for comparison
    factorMelt <- melt(factorMat, id.vars=".Pred", variable.name="Term", )
    # only keep rows where there's a match
    factorMelt <- factorMelt[factorMelt$value == 1, ]
    # again, bring in coefficient if needed
    if(inter == 1)
    {
        factorMelt <- rbind(data.frame(.Pred="(Intercept)", Term="(Intercept)", value=1), factorMelt)
    }
    # join into the matching data.frame
    matching <- join(matching, factorMelt, by="Term")

    return(matching)
}

# fit some models with different terms
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ total_bill * sex + day, tips)
mod2 <- lm(tip ~ total_bill * sex + day - 1, tips)
mod3 <- lm(tip ~ (total_bill + sex + day)^3, tips)
mod4 <- lm(tip ~ total_bill * sex + day + I(total_bill^2), tips)

matchCoefs(mod1)
matchCoefs(mod2)
matchCoefs(mod3)
matchCoefs(mod4)

# now with the convoluted baseball example
baseball <- data.frame(Bat=sample(1:100, 20, replace=T), Batter=sample(c("David", "Batley", "Bob", "Ace"), 20, replace=T), Hits=sample(1:20, 20, replace=T))
bMod <- lm(Hits ~ Bat*Batter, baseball)
matchCoefs(bMod)
```

No loops, all built in functions, no regex.  I will need to test this some more and throw in the data type information, but that should be comparatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer but should be able to see a way of rearranging it to suit your purposes. The first step identifies which of the `labels` are in each of the `model.matrix` column names.

```
col.matx <- sapply(colnames(model.matrix(mod)), function(cols) 
         sapply(labels(mod), function(trm) grep(patt=trm, x=cols, value=TRUE)))
#---------------------------------------
               (Intercept) total_bill   sexMale     daySat      daySun      dayThur    
total_bill     Character,0 "total_bill" Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0
sex            Character,0 Character,0  "sexMale"   Character,0 Character,0 Character,0
day            Character,0 Character,0  Character,0 "daySat"    "daySun"    "dayThur"  
total_bill:sex Character,0 Character,0  Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0
sex:day        Character,0 Character,0  Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0
               total_bill:sexMale   sexMale:daySat   sexMale:daySun   sexMale:dayThur  
total_bill     "total_bill:sexMale" Character,0      Character,0      Character,0      
sex            "total_bill:sexMale" "sexMale:daySat" "sexMale:daySun" "sexMale:dayThur"
day            Character,0          "sexMale:daySat" "sexMale:daySun" "sexMale:dayThur"
total_bill:sex "total_bill:sexMale" Character,0      Character,0      Character,0      
sex:day        Character,0          Character,0      Character,0      Character,0
```

The rownames of the result would need to be collapsed associated with the matrix values when the value is not a zero length item:

```
> which(sapply(col.matx, length) != 0 , arr.ind=TRUE)
 [1]  6 12 18 23 28 31 32 34 37 38 42 43 47 48
```

So this picks out the items names from the above matrix and associates them with the term.labels
 using modulo arithmetic:

```
data.frame(coef =  unlist(col.matx[
                      which(sapply(col.matx, length) != 0 , arr.ind=TRUE)] ), 
           term.label =rownames(col.matx)[
                       which(sapply(col.matx, length) != 0 , arr.ind=TRUE) %% 5 ])
                 coef     term.label
1          total_bill     total_bill
2             sexMale            sex
3              daySat            day
4              daySun            day
5             dayThur            day
6  total_bill:sexMale     total_bill
7  total_bill:sexMale            sex
8  total_bill:sexMale total_bill:sex
9      sexMale:daySat            sex
10     sexMale:daySat            day
11     sexMale:daySun            sex
12     sexMale:daySun            day
13    sexMale:dayThur            sex
14    sexMale:dayThur            day
```

Collapsing values methods are a frequent request onSO. There was one that was answered in the last 24 hours.

Comment: This seems similar in spirit to my regular expression solution but then again I'm reviewing this from my phone and can't really see it or test it. I'll give it a go tomorrow and see if it has the same flaw (not fatal, but certainly difficult) that my approach had.

Comment: Edited my post for the case where the regex check would get tricked.